# Как сдвинуть frame на верх? Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Помогите пожалуйста, не могу сдвинуть frame на верх. Необходимо сделать так чтобы справа от списка игр было меню где будет указываться информация о игре и предложении скачать её, но frame почему то не получается сдвинуть на верх, что делать? вот весь код приложения:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Button, ttk
from tkinter import Tk, RIGHT, BOTH, RAISED
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Button, Style

Window_width = 640
Window_height = 480

class Fullscreen_Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("MarketBlackGames by DanyaGavrin",)
        self.window.geometry(str(Window_width) + "x" + str(Window_height))
        self.window.config(bg = "#000000");
        self.window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
        self.fullScreenState = False
        self.window.bind("<F11>", self.toggleFullScreen)
        self.window.bind("<Escape>", self.quitFullScreen)
        s = Style()
        s.configure('My.TFrame', background="#b46ec2")
        self.frame = Frame(relief=RAISED, borderwidth=1, height= 120, style='My.TFrame')
        self.label = Label(self.frame, text = "MarketBlackGames by DanyaGavrin", bg = "#b46ec2", height= 2).pack()
        self.frame.pack(fill = BOTH)
        self.frame.config()
        
        self.GameList = Frame(relief=RAISED, borderwidth=1, style="My.TFrame", )
        self.NameListGame =  Label(self.GameList, text= "Список игр", bg = "#b46ec2").pack()
        self.GameListBase =  Frame(self.GameList, relief= RAISED, borderwidth= 1)
        self.GameListBase.pack()
        self.rad1 = Radiobutton(self.GameListBase, text='HistoryGirl', value=1, bg = "#b46ec2", height= 4, command= self.HG, anchor=W, width= 30)  
        self.rad2 = Radiobutton(self.GameListBase, text='HistoryGirl: Новые рассветы', value=2, bg = "#b46ec2", height= 4, command= self.HG2, anchor=W, width=30)  
        self.rad3 = Radiobutton(self.GameListBase, text='HardcoreQuiz', value=3, bg = "#b46ec2", height= 4, command = self.HG3, anchor = W, width=30)  
        self.rad1.grid(column=0, row=0)  
        self.rad2.grid(column=0, row=1)  
        self.rad3.grid(column=0, row=2)
        self.GameList.pack(anchor = W)
        self.GameList.config()

        self.window.mainloop()

    def toggleFullScreen(self, event):
        self.fullScreenState = not self.fullScreenState
        self.window.attributes("-fullscreen", self.fullScreenState)

    def quitFullScreen(self, event):
        self.fullScreenState = False
        self.window.attributes("-fullscreen", self.fullScreenState)

    def HG(self):
        print("HistoryGirl")
        self.HistoryGirl = Frame(relief= RAISED, borderwidth=0, style="My.TFrame", width= 500, height= Window_height).pack(anchor= N)
    
    def HG2(self):
        print("HistoryGirl: Новые рассветы")

    def HG3(self):
        print("HardcoreQuiz")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Fullscreen_Example()
```

[image]

Comment: прикрепляйте код текстом в тело вопроса с использованием соответствующего форматирования. В таком виде (с фотографий) его разбирать никто не будет

Comment: Например, `self.GameListBase.pack(side=LEFT)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше явно указывать на родительский элемент при размещении виджетов. Тогда вам легче будет позиционировать их, а так по умолчанию они располагаются на self.window.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Button, ttk
from tkinter import Tk, RIGHT, BOTH, RAISED
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Button, Style

Window_width = 640
Window_height = 480


class Fullscreen_Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("MarketBlackGames by DanyaGavrin", )
        self.window.geometry(str(Window_width) + "x" + str(Window_height))
        self.window.config(bg="#000000");
        self.window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
        self.fullScreenState = False
        self.window.bind("<F11>", self.toggleFullScreen)
        self.window.bind("<Escape>", self.quitFullScreen)
        s = Style()
        s.configure('My.TFrame', background="#b46ec2")
        self.frame = Frame(self.window, relief=RAISED, borderwidth=1, height=120, style='My.TFrame')
        self.label = Label(self.frame, text="MarketBlackGames by DanyaGavrin", bg="#b46ec2", height=2).pack()
        self.frame.pack(fill=BOTH)
        self.frame.config()

        self.GameList = Frame(self.frame, relief=RAISED, borderwidth=1, style="My.TFrame", )
        self.NameListGame = Label(self.GameList, text="Список игр", bg="#b46ec2").pack()
        self.GameListBase = Frame(self.GameList, relief=RAISED, borderwidth=1)
        self.GameListBase.pack()
        self.rad1 = Radiobutton(self.GameListBase, text='HistoryGirl', value=1, bg="#b46ec2", height=4, command=self.HG,
                                anchor=W, width=30)
        self.rad2 = Radiobutton(self.GameListBase, text='HistoryGirl: Новые рассветы', value=2, bg="#b46ec2", height=4,
                                command=self.HG2, anchor=W, width=30)
        self.rad3 = Radiobutton(self.GameListBase, text='HardcoreQuiz', value=3, bg="#b46ec2", height=4,
                                command=self.HG3, anchor=W, width=30)
        self.rad1.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.rad2.grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.rad3.grid(column=0, row=2)
        self.GameList.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.GameList.config()

        self.window.mainloop()

    def toggleFullScreen(self, event):
        self.fullScreenState = not self.fullScreenState
        self.window.attributes("-fullscreen", self.fullScreenState)

    def quitFullScreen(self, event):
        self.fullScreenState = False
        self.window.attributes("-fullscreen", self.fullScreenState)

    def HG(self):
        print("HistoryGirl")
        self.HistoryGirl = Frame(self.frame, relief=RAISED, borderwidth=0, style="My.TFrame", width=500, height=Window_height)
        self.HistoryGirl.pack(side=LEFT)

    def HG2(self):
        print("HistoryGirl: Новые рассветы")

    def HG3(self):
        print("HardcoreQuiz")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Fullscreen_Example()
```